# is there a way to use d3.js for svg markup not embedded in the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

Is there a way to use d3.js for svg markup not embedded in the page?  For example, this jsfiddle url shows a good simple example of using d3 with embedded svg markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/nkint/Ga8UJ/2/

```
var svg = d3.select("#container svg");
```

How would I (or could I) implement the example at the url above if I wanted to keep the svg markup in its own separate file?

Comment: if svg mark up is in a separate file. what is that you want to show ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you you could use `<object type="blah" data="img.tif"></object>` as it defines an embedded object inside the DOM